# How can I find the general term of sequence with this relations?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is given that $a_1=1$ and $a_2=0.5$ satisfying that for all integers $ n \ge2$

$$n(n+1)a_{n+1}a_n+na_na_{n-1}=(n+1)^2a_{n+1}a_{n-1}$$

How can I found the general term of the sequence ${a_n}$ ?

I try to use the recurrence relations and think about using mathematical induction, but failed because of insufficient data.

Can I get some clues?

Comment: What are the first few terms?

Comment: @vadim123 $a_1=1$ and $a_2=0.5$ is given.

Comment: What are the next 10 terms?

Comment: just curious, where is the problem from?

Comment: You should start by solving the equation for $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n,a_{n-1}$.  Then I would plug it into a spreadsheet to generate a bunch of terms.  It seems to go rapidly to zero.

Comment: try this here $$a_n=\frac{4-4 e \Gamma (2,1)}{3 e n \Gamma (n,1)+(1-4 e \Gamma (2,1)) \Gamma (n+1)}$$

Comment: user362325 I believe you asked this earlier.  Did you delete the earlier question you wrote, in order to ask it again?  In any case: you've earlier asked a question concluding  "I try to use the recurrence relations and think about using mathematical induction, but failed because of insufficient data."

Comment: Copying and pasting such "lines"  makes it very, very easy to connect you to repeated postings, and shows you're simply copying and pasting part of an earlier question.

Comment: @user362325 It is quite concerning that the "two" answers are the only answerers in each of your last 2 posts.  I'll check your other posts, and answerers.

Comment: Well, now since you deleted the second to last questions you ask, (which Arpit happened to also answer), it is clear you are gaming the site, and creating other accounts to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange the equation, you get
$$(n+1)^2\,a_{n+1}\,a_{n-1}-n(n+1)\,a_{n+1}\,a_n\,=n\,a_n\,a_{n-1}$$

$$(n+1)\,a_{n+1}\,\{(n+1)\,a_{n-1}-na_n\}=n\,a_n.a_{n-1}$$
$${(n+1)\,a_{n-1}\,-n\,a_n\over n.a_n.a_{n-1}}={1\over{(n+1)\,a_{n+1}}}$$
$${1\over a_n}-{1\over a_{n-1}}={1\over{(n+1)\,a_{n+1}}}\,\,-{1\over {n\,a_n}}$$

Now on putting the values  $$n=2,3,......,n-1,n$$
And adding all the equations, you get

$${a_{n+1}\over a_n}={1\over(n+1)}$$
$${a_n\over{a_{n-1}}}\cdot{{a_{n-1}\over{a_{n-2}}}}\cdots\cdots {a_2\over a_1}={{1\over n}\cdot}{1\over{n-1}}\cdots\cdots{1\over2}\cdot{1\over1}$$
$$a_n={1\over n!}$$

Comment: This solution is beautiful.

Comment: @user362325  It is unbecoming of you to "brag" or "boast" about an answer from a sockpuppet account of yours.

Comment: @amWhy: How can you be sure that there is a sockpuppet account of user362325?

Answer (score 0):

Given that $a_1=1$, $a_2=\frac{1}{2}$. Putting $n=2,3,\dots~~$ we find that
\begin{align*}
a_3&=\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3!}\\
a_4&=\frac{1}{2^3.3}=\frac{1}{4!}\\
a_5&=\frac{1}{2^3.3.5}=\frac{1}{5!}\\
a_6&=\frac{1}{2^4.3^2.5}=\frac{1}{6!}
\end{align*}
and so on. So, $$a_n=\frac{1}{n!}.$$ In fact, assuming $~a_n=\frac{1}{n!}~$ is true for some $n$,
\begin{align*}
(n+1)a_{n+1}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+n\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}&=(n+1)^2a_{n+1}\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\\
\implies\qquad (n+1)a_{n+1}+\frac{1}{((n-1)!}&=(n+1)^2a_{n+1}\\
\implies\qquad\qquad\qquad a_{n+1}&=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}.
\end{align*}